# Security constraints do not force user to log in

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an app that I want only the administrators to access. I added the following to my web.xml file:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
  <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

However this does not force the user to log like the documentation says it does. If the user is logged in and an admin they can access the site just fine. Otherwise 403 is returned.

The app is built with App Engine SDK v1.8.9 and GWT SDK v2.6.0

Am I misunderstanding the documentation or doing something wrong?

Comment: Which authentication option is set for your application?

Comment: I am using the Google Accounts API.

Comment: Try /_ah/ in your app's domain to make sure that you are logged out of all Google accounts.

Comment: I get a 404 error when trying to access /_ah/

Comment: Strange, this is a reserved handler. What happens when you hit http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/ on your development server?

Comment: I cannot directly access /_ah/ on my development server either. However I can access /_ah/admin on my development server which is the admin console. Also I noticed that when I logout or login through the app the url has /_ah/ in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple AuthServlet to your project. Map it in web.xml to `/_ah/` - or another handler like `/login`. Use it to check if you are logged into a Google account.

```
public class AuthServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

        HashSet<String> attributes = new HashSet<String>();

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        if (user != null) {
            out.println("Hello <i>" + user.getNickname() + "</i>!");
            out.println("[<a href=\""
                    + userService.createLogoutURL(req.getRequestURI())
                    + "\">sign out</a>]");
        } else {
            String redirect = req.getRequestURI();
            out.println("Sign in at: ");
                String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL(
                        redirect, null, "www.google.com/accounts/o8/id", attributes);
                out.println("[<a href=\"" + loginUrl + "\">Google</a>] ");
        }
     }
}
```